# Parquet file Issue: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, parquet

I'm trying to practice linear regression with two targets. However I keep getting this error that I believe is due either to the data being a parquet file or me having to convert the test data. The training seemed fine but when I try predicting with the test set I get the following error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


TRAIN = pd.read_parquet('train.parquet')

y_train = TRAIN['a'], TRAIN['z']
x_train = TRAIN.drop('a', axis=1)
x_train = x_train.drop('z', axis=1)

y_train = np.asarray(y_train).transpose()

model = LinearRegression()
r = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

```
TEST = pd.read_parquet('test.parquet')

TEST_list = list(TEST)

predict = model.predict([TEST_list])
print(predict(0))
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/1089482654.py in <module>
      4 TEST_list = list(TEST)
      5 
----> 6 predict = model.predict([TEST_list])
      7 print(predict(0))
...

ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'
```

To my understanding the error is telling me to convert the test data. I wanted to know if this is the case.

Comment: What is the type of `TEST`?

Comment: The types in the TEST data frame are Int64

Comment: You really must provide a [mcve]